# DF transform with multiple combinations

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm a beginner at R.

How do I transform DF like this?

I tried to make DF contain the count of two factors' combinations.

When the conditions are as follows; Consult_A == 1 & Reply_A == 1 in each id,  the count is counted as "1". In this transformation, I want to get the flow of connection between item of consult and reply.

```
# original DF
df= data.frame(
          id = c(1L, 2L),
   Consult_A = c(1L, 1L),
   Consult_B = c(1L, 0L),
   Consult_C = c(1L, 0L),
     Reply_A = c(1L, 1L),
     Reply_B = c(0L, 0L),
     Reply_C = c(1L, 1L)
)


# answer DF (I want to get every combination of Consult and Reply)
ans_omit = data.frame(
           Consult = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
             Reply = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
             Count = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
)
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. How is `Count` calculated? Can you walk us through the logic/calculation for e.g. `Consult = B, Reply = A, Count = 2` based on the input data?

Comment: Maurits Evers, Thanks for your reply. I edited the question in detail. Please check it. Best regards.

Comment: I still don't understand how you calculate `Count`. Why is `Count = 2` for `Consult = A, Reply = C`. What does `Count` measure? Please *explicitly* show your logic/calculation based on the input data you give for at least one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be easier to manage in a tidier format. First, you can use `pivot_longer` to put into long form, and remove those factors that are zero:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c("var", "factor"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(-value)

df_long

     id var     factor
  <int> <chr>   <chr> 
1     1 Consult A     
2     1 Consult B     
3     1 Consult C     
4     1 Reply   A     
5     1 Reply   C     
6     2 Consult A     
7     2 Reply   A     
8     2 Reply   C
```

Then, you can do a `full_join` between "Consult" and "Reply" to get combinations between the two. Finally, count up distinct `id` to get the desired `Count` column, and use `complete` to add combinations where there are zero counts.

```
full_join(
  df_long %>% filter(var == "Consult") %>% rename(Consult = factor),
  df_long %>% filter(var == "Reply") %>% rename(Reply = factor),
  by = "id"
) %>%
  group_by(Consult, Reply) %>%
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(id)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Consult, Reply = unique(Consult), fill = list(Count = 0))
```

**Output**

```
  Consult Reply Count
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 A       A         2
2 A       B         0
3 A       C         2
4 B       A         1
5 B       B         0
6 B       C         1
7 C       A         1
8 C       B         0
9 C       C         1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a beginner at R. So this answer is helpful for me.